# How to retreive text in similar tag with beautifulsoup?

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

How to ignore the `<span class="label-negative"` and get text percent value in `<span style="color: #3F8539">` and `#A9CF54`?

[image: screenshot of output]

```
#url = 'https://www.dotabuff.com/heroes/trends'

cont = soup.find_all("td", attrs = {"r-tab r-group-1 cell-centered"})
cont
```

Comment: Please don't shate text as an image. Edit your question and add the xml as text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To load the table from the site I recommend to use `pd.read_html()`:

```py
from io import StringIO

import pandas as pd

url = "https://www.dotabuff.com/heroes/trends"
headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:120.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/120.0"
}

df = pd.read_html(StringIO(requests.get(url, headers=headers).text))[0]
df = (
    df.droplevel(0, axis=1)
    .set_index(("Unnamed: 0_level_1", "Hero"))
    .rename_axis(index=None)
)

print(df.head(10))
```

Prints:

```
                 Win Rate                       Pick Rate                      
                    Start Current  Change Trend     Start Current  Change Trend
Shadow Demon       46.33%  48.10%  +1.78%   NaN     2.07%   2.37%  +0.30%   NaN
Ember Spirit       49.38%  51.00%  +1.62%   NaN     5.75%   7.08%  +1.32%   NaN
Bane               49.85%  51.15%  +1.30%   NaN     2.46%   2.85%  +0.39%   NaN
Chen               46.70%  47.72%  +1.03%   NaN     1.02%   0.96%  -0.05%   NaN
Nature's Prophet   48.47%  49.45%  +0.98%   NaN    16.80%  17.30%  +0.50%   NaN
Troll Warlord      50.77%  51.73%  +0.96%   NaN     5.37%   5.17%  -0.20%   NaN
Lone Druid         51.32%  52.28%  +0.96%   NaN     3.05%   3.13%  +0.08%   NaN
Disruptor          49.34%  50.25%  +0.91%   NaN     5.86%   6.13%  +0.27%   NaN
Viper              52.77%  53.59%  +0.82%   NaN    12.99%  13.84%  +0.86%   NaN
Lina               45.89%  46.65%  +0.75%   NaN    13.83%  13.81%     NaN   NaN
```

Comment: yea my purpose is to extract the table data and convert it to csv file

Comment: @Rizal You can then save the dataframe to CSV (`df.to_csv(...)`). Before you can remove the multi-index columns, rename them etc.

Comment: btw thank for your knowledge sir, i just knew about pd.read_html

Comment: @Rizal So this should be a detail of your question ;) in case of  extracting whole table `pd.read_html()` would also be my favorite.

Comment: @HedgeHog haha yes, many thank to both of you guys. i will continue to learn about that;)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [`css selector`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) to select more spezific and exclude the negatives:

```
soup.select('td.r-group-1:not(:has(span.label-negative))')
```

or select them by its color:

```
soup.select('td.r-group-1:has(span[style="color: #3F8539"],span[style="color: #A9CF54"])')
```

To get the text of the elements simply iterate one of these `ResultSets` and call `get_text()`:

```
[s.get_text(strip= True) for s in soup.select('td.r-group-1:has(span[style="color: #3F8539"],span[style="color: #A9CF54"])')]
```

Comment: This is good!, but how to exclude the "..cell-divider" on it?